# Using a variable GetObject argument

Tags: vbscript

The following code provides the desired result:

```
Set myobj = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk='c:'")
```

But how do I replace 'c' with a string variable? The following, which seems logical, does NOT work!

```
Set myobj = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk='" & myvariable & ":'")
```

Nor does

```
Set myobj = GetObject("""winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk='" & myvariable & ":'""")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
Set myobj = GetObject("winmgmts:\.\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk='c:'")
```

does **not** 'work', but throws an [error](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/code/code_80041021.htm). Correct is:

```
Set myobj = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk='c:'")
```

Then - assuming myvariable is (named and) initialized decently - all is well:

```
>> s1 = "winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk='c:'"
>> WScript.Echo "s1:", s1
>> myvariable = "c"
>> s2 = "winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk='" & myvariable & ":'"
>> WScript.Echo "s2:", s2
>> WScript.Echo "s1 = s2:", CStr(s1 = s2)
>>
s1: winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk='c:'
s2: winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk='c:'
s1 = s2: True
```